# Error Docker compose configure listener for kafka Service. No Broker available

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I try to setup a docker-compose with Kafka @ Wurstmeister.

**SCENARIO:**
I develop an Architecture of multiple microservices. In concrete: I have a spring boot app that sends JSON to my kafka broker. A Flask service consumes the data.
This works when running the whole think outside docker. I am also able to send data to the kafka Topic in docker.

**CODE:**
Flask:

```
KafkaHost = "kafka:9092"
def initkafka():
    # connect to Kafka server and pass the topic we want to consume
    consumer = KafkaConsumer("TEST",
                             group_id='view',
                             bootstrap_servers=[Constants.KafkaHost]
                             )
    KafkaConsumer(auto_offset_reset='latest',
                  enable_auto_commit=False)

    KafkaConsumer(value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.dedoce('utf-8')))
    KafkaConsumer(consumer_timeout_ms=1000)
    return consumer
```

Docker Compose:

```
zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - test-net

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      #KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 172.17.0.1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://172.17.0.1:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "TEST:1:1"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - test-net
```

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from controller import Controller
  File "/app/controller/Controller.py", line 27, in <module>
    consumer = KafkaConfig.initkafka()
  File "/app/config/KafkaConfig.py", line 16, in initkafka
    enable_auto_commit=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 324, in __init__
    self._client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, **self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 826, in check_version
    raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

I think that it is a problem of the environment configuration. I've read the wurstmeister doc but I can't figure out what I need to setup to make my flask service find the kafka broker. 
The logs say that kafka is up an running und the topic " TEST " gets is created.
Do I have to configure the listeners e.g. say with ip and port in my network will listen to kafka ? Because in the [kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerapi) advertised.listeners is described as

> Listeners to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to use, if different than the listeners config property. In IaaS environments, this may need to be different from the interface to which the broker binds. If this is not set, the value for listeners will be used. Unlike listeners it is not valid to advertise the 0.0.0.0 meta-address.

Comment: do you have the flask app as a container or deployed on your localhost directly ?

Comment: Both. I tried my compose file only with the flask service and it's mongodb instance. I disabled the kafka connection and it works. But when I enable the Kafka connection I get the error. When running the whole project (all services involved) with kafka it also works fine. So to run it in my container I just changed "localhost" to the name of the service in my compose file

Comment: from flask container, if you can get a positive result from `ping kafka` then try `telnet kafka 9092` if you got connnection refused then make sure that kafka is bind on `0.0.0.0` so other containers can access it

Comment: set the following environment variable as `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092`

Comment: when using `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092` I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: advertised.listeners cannot use the nonroutable meta-address 0.0.0.0. Use a routable IP address.` sry stacktrace to long for comment

Comment: Please read https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` needs to have the same value as the kafka host that you define in your flask client. Thus, if you are connecting to Kafka from inside a docker container, you should have `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092`. If connecting from the host, it should be `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092`.

Alternatively, you may omit the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` setting and define instead `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka`.

Comment: What to you exactly mean by connections from inside a container and from the host. I thought this is publish subscribe. So My Kafka Container offers a host:port inside my docker network to subscribe to read from topics. This host should be de DNS entry ( service name ) of my docker service?
When I use ` KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 ` I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Each listener must have a different port, listeners: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092`

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my answer, then. My point is that the advertised listeners must correspond to the hostname that the consumer uses. So, yes, when flask is running inside docker, the advertised listener is equal to the DNS entry of the docker service, aka: "kafka".

Comment: Ok and because of the error NoBrokersAvailable and the logs I'm sure that the Topic gets created. Is there something else I might check instead to the configs?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand your question :-/ Are the proposed settings working for you?

Comment: I'm sorry, my comment was kind of confusing. I justed want to say that after having a look at the logs I'm sure that it has to be a problem with the listener configuration.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been gone through [this](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained) mentioned by @cricket_007. It's a bit clearer now but I still struggle with getting the connetion.
As a recap for my scenario: I run all my services and the message broker in the same Docker Network. So there has no external connection to be made. 
In this blog entry there is an example given:

```
KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_BOB://kafka0:29092,LISTENER_FRED://localhost:9092
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_BOB://kafka0:29092,LISTENER_FRED://localhost:9092
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_BOB:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_FRED:PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_BOB
```

I guess I know what this configuration means. 
In my case I thought I have to change it this way:

```
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_PY://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_PY://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_PY:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_PY
```

I guess KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME is not needed because I only got one broker. But does the listener name ( LISTENER_PY ) depend on my Flask Service name or any other property? As far as I understand I can use "kafka" as ip because I run Kafka as a service named "kafka" in my docker-compose. I tried this configuration but still it doesn't work. I wonder how it works from within my spring service to connect as a producer without defining any listener configuration.